# IOS 7 Navigation bar overlapping Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios7, navigationbar

I had developed an app earlier for ios 4 and above, in which I had used 2 navigation bars on top. 1 was a global bar common for all the views and the other changed with the views.

- In IOS 7 the main nav bar is overlapping the navigation bar of the views.
- If I change the position or any other attribute of the navigation bars it renders the views blank.

Is there a way that I can have the view navigation bar below the main navigation bar like it appears in IOS 6?

Thanks in Advance
Moiz Ahmed Sulaiman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to set dgesForExtendedLayout for your VC:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

or change your navigationBar translucent?

```
navigationBar.translucent = NO; // It is YES by default in iOS7.
```

Comment: You saved my Life. been banging my head over this issue for 2 days , was almost depressed.Thanks a lot